# Problem with copying files above ~4.2 GB

Tags: hard-drive, usb, memory, file-sharing

I am trying to copy video (mp4) files from the solid state drive of my MacBook Pro to both a external hard disk as well as to a SanDisk USB thumb drive. It goes well up to abut 4.1 GB file size, but for larger files I get an error message "The item "Filename" cannot be copied. The operation couldn't be completed. File too large".

But the file I am trying to copy is only 4.5 GB, whereas there is about 25 GB free space on the USB thumb drive, and about 1 TB on the external hard disk. Does this possibly depend on the file transfer program? First I tried to use Forklift, and then simply Copy and Paste from one Finder window to another. But always the same error message. I checked if there is a limitation on the size of transferred files in Forklift, but did not find any. I would appreciate if someone could tell me where the bottleneck is.

Comment: How are these disks formatted? Try the Terminal command `cp`. Ex: `cp source_file target_directory`  In Terminal, type `man cp` to find out the details of the options available.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help either: after 4.2 GB copied, it gave the error message 

cp: /Volumes/Rays_videos/IPhO_2008_VN/Ray_VN_2008.mp4: File too large
Imres-MacBook-Pro:IPhO39_2008 imre$

Comment: How are the disks formatted? Get Info on the drives and let us know.

Comment: It is formatted with MS-DOS (FAT32). I guess this may be the problem, because it only allows transfer of files of max 4 GB.